# Oracle_cx - execute many data issues

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am new to this Python and Oracle executemany option.

- I have a dataframe 131 columns wide. One date - all others float and last one string.

> date                object
> open               float64
> high               float64
> low                float64
> close              float64
> ...
> LINEARREG_SLOPE    float64
> STDDEV             float64
> TSF                float64
> VAR                float64
> symbol              object

- I can insert data using the for loop one insert at a time - There are 2 million rows - so it takes hours
- I tested moving to executemany - it works on small 5 columns tests i did. Its fast also.
- when i try to put it on entire 132 columns i get the error below - so i know its not the database.

-- THIS works

```
many = list(df1.to_records(index=False)) 
#print(many)
#rows = [tuple(x) for x in df1.values]
#print(rows)    
cursor.executemany("insert into mytable3 values (to_date(:D,'YYYY-MM-DD'),:open, :high, :low, :close, :volume)" , many)
connect.commit()
```

-- NOW if i add all 132 columns - this FAILS with this error - which does not if i do EXECUTE

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Oracle_CX_ExecuteMany.py", line 597, in <module>
    f_call_add_talib_to_frame_loader('ETF')
   File "Oracle_CX_ExecuteMany.py", line 558, in f_call_add_talib_to_frame_loader
    :symbol )" , many )
    cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type numpy.int32 not supported.
```

-- The code -- the list converted data - many it is not liking. I only have float data as seen above.

Please advise.

Comment: It seems PROBLEM is coming from  df.fillna(0.0, inplace=True)
I am searching how to make this float64 not int32.

Comment: you can also use an input type converter to seamlessly convert from numpy.int32 to whatever value you prefer (float, for example)